# Syntax to adding Geosever TMS

Tags: python, qgis

I want to add Geosever TMS (Tile Map Service) to QGIS, how can I do that?

My Geoserver is local like:
http://localhost:8600/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/ws:tb_district@EPSQ:4326/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding the GetCapabilities URL first? So something like this:

You will have to use the Create New WMS/WMTS Connection option:

http://localhost:8600/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?Service=WMTS&Request=GetCapabilities&Version=1.0.0

There's a video tutorial on the topic here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LW5_Tz_32g&ab_channel=RoelVandePaar